# Position icon in the middle of the text

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am having an issue with positioning in CSS. Now I have an icon and text like this :

[Icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kl6A.png)

But I want to make the icon go to the middle of the text. How do I do that?

Comment: by using `flex` in css

Comment: 'flex' to where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Flex](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp).

Live code: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/amryasser32/pen/mdxdvrj)

HTML:

```
   <div class='alert'>
      <span class='alert-icon'>icon</span>
      <div class='alert-content'>
        <div>text</div>
        <div>text</div>
        <div>text</div>
      </div>
      <span class='alert-close-icon'> close icon </span>
   </div>
```

CSS:

```
.alert {
  background-color: red;
  color:#fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 250px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 10px 10px
}
```

Just add the images and replace them with the text inside `.alert-icon` `.alert-close-icon`

Answer (score 0):

Just use `display: flex` and `align-items: center` on the parent container of two block of elements to aligns.

```css
.inlineElements {
  display: flex;
}

.alignItemsCenter {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; /* Pack items around the center */
}

.content {
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="inlineElements">

  <div class='alignItemsCenter'>
    <i class="fa-regular fa-circle-xmark"></i>
    
    <div class="content">
      <div>
        Hello
      </div>
      <div>
        Display
      </div>
      <div>
        Flex
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <i class="fa-solid fa-xmark"></i>
<div>
```